# drop the rows that contain the null values from columns with a specific word [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a format

```
  name breed year animal_a animal_b animal_c
0 chr  chr   num  nan      nan      nan 
1 chr  chr   num  nan      a        nan 
2 chr  chr   num  nan      b        c
```

I'm trying to drop the rows that contain all nan from columns animal_a, animal_b, animal_c.
But since there are a lot of columns that contain the word "animal", I've tried to subset the columns that contain the word first.

```
subset = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('animal')]
```

and then drop the rows with all nan values from the columns that contain the word "animal"

```
df.dropna(axis = 0, subset = subset)
```

But it gives me an error.
I want my final dataframe to look like this:

```
  name breed year animal_a animal_b animal_c
0 chr  chr   num  nan      a        nan 
1 chr  chr   num  nan      b        c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter columns names first and then add `how='all'` to [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove rows with all `NaN`s per only animals columns:

```
#if necessary convert strings nan to missing values NaN
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)

subset = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('animal')]

df = df.dropna(subset = subset, how='all') 
print (df)
  name breed year  animal_a animal_b animal_c
1  chr   chr  num       NaN        a      NaN
2  chr   chr  num       NaN        b        c
```

Or filter by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
mask = df.replace('nan', np.nan).filter(like='animal').isna().all(axis=1)
df = df[~mask]
print (df)
  name breed year animal_a animal_b animal_c
1  chr   chr  num      NaN        a      NaN
2  chr   chr  num      NaN        b        c
```